# Linear model with interation for circular data in R

Tags: r, regression, circular-statistics

I have a circular dependant variable (in radians) and a linear independant variable (year) which I would like to model against each other and extract a slope value. I have been trying to use `lm.circular` from the `circular` package  in `R` but there are some things I don't understand.

Firstly, I don't understand what the `init` argument does. The help states:

> a vector with initial values of length equal to the columns of x

However, if we query lm.`circular` and look at the example given for a model with a circular dependant variable and a linear independant variable:

```
x <- cbind(rnorm(10), rep(1, 10))
y <- circular(2*atan(c(x%*%c(5,1))))+rvonmises(10, mu=circular(0), kappa=100)

lm.circular(y=y, x=x, init=c(5,1), type='c-l',verbose=TRUE)
```

Here `x` has 2 columns with 10 values in each but in the model `init` is `c(5,1)`. How does this work? And why does `x` have 2 columns at all?

If I run my data (with `init` set to 1 as `x` has 1 column) then it runs with no errors but it takes ages compared to the example model:

```
x2 <- as.numeric(c(2001:2014))
y2 <- as.circular(c(-2.68666257, 2.89266865, -2.46348932,  0.29184194,
                   -2.76391485,  0.04291793, -2.44632215, -2.88408506,
                   -1.21886928, -2.78108202, -2.96133734, -2.85833430,
                   -2.90125223,  0.37767781))

m1 <- lm.circular(y = y2, x = x2, type = "c-l", init=1)

summary(m1)

             Length Class    Mode   
x            14     -none-   numeric
y            14     -none-   numeric
mu            1     circular numeric
se.mu         1     -none-   numeric
kappa         1     -none-   numeric
se.kappa      1     -none-   numeric
coefficients  1     -none-   numeric
cov.coef      1     -none-   numeric
se.coef       1     -none-   numeric
log.lik       1     -none-   numeric
t.values      1     -none-   numeric
p.values      1     -none-   numeric
call          4     -none-   call
```

As an experiment I substituted the values in the example with the first 10 `x` and `y` values in my data but got an error immediately:

```
x <- cbind(rnorm(10), rep(1, 10))
y <- circular(2*atan(c(x%*%c(5,1))))+rvonmises(10, mu=circular(0), kappa=100)

x[,1] <- as.numeric(c(2001:2010))
y <- y2[1:10]

lm.circular(y=y, x=x, init=c(5,1), type='c-l',verbose=TRUE)

Iteration  1 :    Log-Likelihood =  NA 
Error in while (diff > tol) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Although my model seems to be running ok, I'm not confident that I've understood the lm.`circular` function and that therefore my model isn't nonsense. If anyone is able to help me understand the function, and particulalry `init`, I would be very grateful.

Finally, what I really want is to incorporate an interaction into my model, but I haven't been able to find a way to do this with lm.`circular`. I essentially want to run this, where `y` is circular:

```
glm(y ~ x * z)
```

Is there a way to do this?

This question was previously posted in stackoverflow but it was suggested that it might do better here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several questions encapsulated in one, so I'll adress them separately.

**Columns of ones**

First, the example is given in such a way because a common way to model the intercept is to add a column of ones to the predictor. You can see this by noting that, in the linear model:

$$y = \alpha + \boldsymbol\beta^T \boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol\beta' ^T\boldsymbol{x}',$$

where the only difference between $\boldsymbol\beta$ and $\boldsymbol\beta'$ is that the latter has one additional parameter (the intercept), and the difference between $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{x}'$ is that the latter has one additional column consisting of all ones.

In that same notation, the circular regression model (in the case where we add a column of ones) is a little bit more complicated:
$$y = \alpha + 2 \tan^{-1}(\boldsymbol\beta' \boldsymbol{x}') = \alpha + 2 \tan^{-1}(\gamma + \boldsymbol\beta \boldsymbol{x}).$$ Here, the $\alpha$ is a circular intercept parameter, which determines where on the circle the 'middle' (inflection point) of the inverse-tangent link function is placed. In `lm.circular` this parameter is called `mu`, even though it's interpretation is not really that of a mean direction.

The interesting parameter is the one which I call  $\gamma$ here. It acts as a kind of intercept on the scale of the predictors and it determines what part of the shape of the link function will be used. In the example, this means that the regression parameter is initialized at 5, and the $\gamma$ is initialized at one.

If we do not include a column of ones, the model can still be totally valid. With  $\gamma = 0,$ we use the middle of the inverse-tangent link function, which is approximately linear. This model is slightly more parsimonious, but it will fit badly if the relationships in the data are not roughly linear.

**Initialization of `lm.circular`**

Second, on the use of `lm.circular`. You note that the model takes a very long time to run. The reason is that the likelihood of circular regression models is strongly irregular. Therefore, optimization is difficult, and you need to specify appropriate starting values. This is discussed for example in [Gill & Hangartner, 2010](http://www.hangartner.net/files/gillhangartner10paeng.pdf).

If the model takes this long to run, it almost surely *has not converged*, and the results should not be interpreted. You either need to find good starting values somehow, your data does not fit the data well, or you need more data.

An alternative is to switch to another package to estimate these models which don't depend so strongly on the starting values. For example, you can use [`circglmbayes`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=circglmbayes) (Full disclosure: I am the author of that package), for which I'll give an example in the next section.

**Interaction**

Third, you mention you want to run an interaction. You can run these in `lm.circular`, but you need to calculate the interaction variables yourself and include them as additional variables in the model (you could use `model.matrix`). If you want the GLM specification you mention, in `circglmbayes` you can do the following, which has the interaction code as you mention:

```
library(circglmbayes)

# Simulate data
x3 <- cbind(x = c(2001:2014, 2001:2014),
            g = c(rep(0, 14), rep(1, 14)))

y3 <- (1 + 2*atan(c(scale(x3) %*% c(.4, .1))) +
         rvonmises(28, mu = circular(0), kappa = 50)) %% (2*pi)

# Add interaction
y3 <- (y3 + c(14:1 / 6, rep(0, 14))) %% (2*pi)

# Collect and plot data
df <- data.frame(cbind(x3, y = y3))
plot(y ~ x, col = ifelse(df$g, "red", "blue"), df)

# Run model without interaction
cgm_noint <- circGLM(y ~ x + g, data = df)

# Run model without interaction
cgm_int <- circGLM(y ~ x * g, data = df)

cgm_noint
cgm_int
```

As a final note, if you have any categorical predictors in the model (in the interaction or otherwise), the `lm.circular` model forces each of the groups to use a different part of the regression function. This can lead to the model depending on the arbitrary reference category. For details, see [Mulder & Klugkist, 2017](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022249616300827) (again, I am the author, but it is certainly relevant). This is another thing that is addressed naturally in `circglmbayes`.

Comment: Thank you for this Kees. Could you possibly expand on the code for the interaction as I don't really understand it and I'm not sure how to make it work with my data? My covariates are year and pixel, columns x and g in your example. My data is extracted from a stack of 14 rasters. Each raster corresponds to a year from 2001:2014 and has 2150 pixels. However, the data is incomplete so I have removed pixels with less than 3 data points.There are 867 remaining pixels, with between 3 and 14 data points each. My objective is to extract from the model the slope the change in radians in each pixel.

Comment: The formula syntax (for example `y ~ x + g + x*g`) is exactly the same as the standard in `glm()` or `lm()`.

Assuming we're going to ignore spatial dependence (which will make the model more uncertain, because there are only 14 observation for each group), you can simply make a factor `pixel` denoting the name of the pixel for each observation (in long format), and running `circGLM(y ~ year * pixel, data = df)`.

You can also try to get more power in each group by grouping together similar or close pixels.